# how to interact with combo boxes in testcomplete 10?

Tags: vbscript, combobox, testcomplete

I am using a C sharp .NET application and Testcomplete is not recognising the combo boxes using the object Spy. and since I cannot map it , the object spy doesn't not give me any methods related to combo boxes like e.g.. ClickItem function.
please give an workable solution or an alternative to access the items in the combo boxes .

Comment: Do you use a standard combo box control or a custom one from a third-party vendor? Put here the value of the ClrFullClassName property of the control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like TestComplete doesn't recognize your app correctly.
Check the version of TestComplete and the version of .NET Framework installed on your computer (and the one used to build your app). TestComplete may not support the .NET Framework version you use. For example, if you are using TestComplete 9.31, it works with .NET Framework 4.5 and earlier. If .NET Framework 4.5.1 is used in your app, you need to use TestComplete 10.

Comment: my application is built with .NET 4.0 and I am using Testcomplete 10 . It is supported if I am not mistaken.

Comment: This Framework version is supported in TestComplete 10 indeed. What combobox control are you using? Check the value of the ClrFullClassName property of the control in TestComplete's Object Browser.

Comment: I am using the LookupEdit control for comboboxes

Comment: What is the vendor of your LookUpEdit control? I've found this sample that demonstrates how to test a Developer Express LookUpEdit control: http://support.smartbear.com/viewarticle/8979/

Comment: thanks for your help .. got it working using a custom function